# Spotify Refresh Token Python

Tags: python, api, oauth, spotify, refresh-token

I have a python program that returns whatever song I'm currently listening to. The Access Token I get from Spotify API only lasts an hour and I'm having trouble finding an easy way to implement a refresh token into my code.

```
    SPOTIFY_GET_CURRENT_TRACK_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player'
SPOTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'BQBQMLkkLb6az9TRv-PDXFFcm4KHrofc67H12Uzs3FXaPWHETy4ivnC-WGu2Jg5wlZ_yhggGypiO0Gnv_QkNGkefTuCjNR_Tzjw4pv2W9f_9_D7-LfD2W5KVPzh2DxMmf9TNPpSn200D_Xd4AD8F_MeJc-DIlA'

#Method to return the info for the currently playing track
def get_current_track():
    response = requests.get(
        SPOTIFY_GET_CURRENT_TRACK_URL,
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {SPOTIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
        }
    )
    resp_json = response.json()

    track_id = resp_json['item']['id']
    track_name = resp_json['item']['name']
    artists = resp_json['item']['artists']
    artists_name = ', '.join(
        [artist['name'] for artist in artists]
    )
    link = resp_json['item']['external_urls']['spotify']

    current_track_info = {
        "id" : track_id,
        "name" : track_name,
        "artists" : artists_name,
        "link" : link
    }

    return current_track_info
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a class to keep the token and then request again if it's stale?  Something like this:

```
class SpotifyTracker:
    TRACK_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player'

    def __init__(self):
        self._token = self._set_token()

    def _set_token(self):
        # ... logic to set token

    def _request_track_data(self):
        return requests.get(
            self.TRACK_URL,
            headers={
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {self._token}"
            }
        )

    def get_current_track(self):
        response = self._request_track_data() 
        if response.code == 401:
            self._set_token()
            response = self._request_track_data()
        resp_json = response.json()
        ...
        return current_track_info
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is actually refreshing the token. Right now I use a temp one from Spotify and it only lasts an hour.

Comment: Maybe you could post something about how you are trying to get the token?  If you can get it in an automated way for an hour couldn't you just do the above?  ie automatically refetch it on an http 401

Comment: So right now I'm using a temporary Auth Token from Spotify. Spotify has a Authorization code flow but I can't figure out how to use it in my code. https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow

Answer (score 0):

This code is assuming you already have an access token and just need to refresh it:

```py
import base64
import requests

def refesh_the_token(): 

        auth_client = client_id + ":" + client_secret
        auth_encode = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(auth_client.encode()).decode()

        headers = {
            'Authorization': auth_encode,
            }

        data = {
            'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' : refresh_token
            }

        response = requests.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data=data, headers=headers) #sends request off to spotify

        if(response.status_code == 200): #checks if request was valid
            print("The request to went through we got a status 200; Spotify token refreshed")
            response_json = response.json()
            new_expire = response_json['expires_in']
            print("the time left on new token is: "+ str(new_expire / 60) + "min") #says how long
            return response_json["access_token"]
        else:
            print("ERROR! The response we got was: "+ str(response))
```

I made this code by referencing this youtube video, they can explain it way better than I ever could: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FsFT6OwE1A

Notable timestamps in the video are 10:14 & 40:25 (this is to purely supplement my answer as a better way of providing an in-depth explanation about this specific piece of code)